# Node Js MsSql Server Async Query and Procedure Problem

Tags: node.js, async-await, synchronization, pymssql

I need a sync query and results. My function is not waiting database response. Q defer does not work. `await` function does not work. `promise` does not work.

**Used** : Patrik Simek (mssql@4.2.1)

This is my code:

***Api function Code***

```
app.post('/api/LoginStep1', function (request, response) {
    var Lang = request.query.Lang;
    var Body = request.body;
    var User = JSON.parse(Body.User);
    TResponse = {};
    TResponse = DoLogin(Lang, User);
    response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(TResponse, null, 3));
});
```

***Database response function***

```
function DoLogin(Lang, User) {
    //var deferred = Q.defer();
    TResponse = {};
    SqlRequest.input('LangCode', sql.NVarChar, Lang);
    SqlRequest.input('UsernameOrMail', sql.NVarChar, User.Mail);
    SqlRequest.output('Status', sql.Int);
    SqlRequest.output('StatusMessage', sql.NVarChar);

    SqlRequest.execute('SpLoginStep1').then(function (response) {

        //console.log(response.recordset);
        TResponse.Status = response.output.Status;
        TResponse.StatusMessage = response.output.StatusMessage;
        //deferred.resolve(response);
        //return deferred.promise;
        //return callback(null, response);

    }).catch(function (e) {
        //return callback(e, null);
        //deferred.resolve(e.status);
        //deferred.reject(e);
        //return deferred.promise;    
    });
    ////return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correct, your function execution ends before you get a response from the database.

I cannot see the `await` keyword in your code. This is how async functions can be used in a "sync" mode.

Have you seen the [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) for the `mssql` package?